# Duplicate image registries 'index.docker.io' found in the 'imageRegistryCredentials' of container group

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-container-instances

```
[PS C:\Source\VelocityAzurev0.10.0\credentialagent-docker-compose> docker compose up
[+] Running 0/1
 - Group credentialagent-docker-compose  Error                                                                                                                                                                                          1.7s
containerinstance.ContainerGroupsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="DuplicateImageRegistries" Message="Duplicate image registries 'index.docker.io' found in the 'imageRegistryCredentials' of container group 'credentialagent-docker-compose'."
PS C:\Source\VelocityAzurev0.10.0\credentialagent-docker-compose>]
```

This was working for me until this morning with no apparent YAML changes. If I tweak the YAML to use local vs azure resources and use a local Docker context, the compose up works. The prior successful runs were removed with "compose down". I double checked the Azure subscription and there appear to be no Container Instances or Groups present in the resource group.

I can't seem to find any pertinent questions/solutions to this particular error regarding the Code="DuplicateImageRegistries".

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem today . After a huge unsuccessful research  I can deploy my container again after run docker logout.

```
$ docker logout
Removing login credentials for https://index.docker.io/v1/
```

Comment: Why do you think this solved the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this issue in the past where Azure Technical Support team helped to resolve this issue. I would recommend you to create an [Azure Technical Support Ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20Help%20+%20support%20from,provide%20information%20about%20your%20problem.) and get the issue resolved with best support.